# OpenStreetMap not loading in Folium (greyed rectangle)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, openstreetmap, folium

Anyone knows why I couldn't load OpenStreetMap map tiles in Folium (I tried Leafmap and IPyLeaflet and still got the same result) over on Jupyter Notebook? I'm pretty sure the problem here is in OpenStreetMap.

[image]

Comment: The parameter is location, not center. `m = folium.Map(location=[43.705305, -79.3989653], tiles='OpenStreetMap', zoom_start=12)`

Comment: Oops, my bad. But either way, it remains the same. Still a grey rectangle

Comment: I checked with jupyterlab3.3.2 folium0.12.1

Comment: Yeah I'm using the same folium version. Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: Can other environments such as Vscode be checked?

Comment: So I'm not using VSCode here; I'm working in Jupyter Notebook. I'm hoping to be able to view the maps and then have some interaction.

Edit: I just tried in Google Colab and it actually works. I don't know but I'll probably work there instead. I'm guessing there must be something funky going on with my Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: Any JS errors in your browser console? Any browser add-ons that might be causing trouble?

Comment: Eliminate the potential that is Jupyter Notebook and create a .py script for your code and output HTML. If the issue persists, try a different browser.

Comment: Hi everyone! I have just figured out. It seems that OpenStreetMap is working after all on Jupyter Notebook. The problem is with the browser I was using. I was using Brave, not sure why it was not working, but it works well with Chrome and Safari.  Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Review the network traffic in your browser's developer console to see if the map tiles are returning a 200. If your code renders the grey box and there aren't errors in the console, it seems that indicates your code is correct but the map tiles are failing to load on your network.

[image]

Comment: Hi Captain, it seems the problem is with my browser. I don't know why it doesn't work with Brave but seems it does for my Chrome and Safari

Comment: Brave is a security focused browser and is probably blocking the HTTP requests to map tile service and returning HTTP 403 rather than 200.