# Folium not showing map, only a grey box

Tags: python, folium

I have just begun with folium and although a box comes up, with the Leaflet | Data by OpenStreetMap ..| in the lower right hand corner, the box doesn't show a map. The code is simple

```
import folium
from folium import Choropleth, Circle, Marker
from folium.plugins import HeatMap, MarkerCluster

# Create a map
m_1 = folium.Map(location=[42.32,-71.0589], tiles='openstreetmap', zoom_start=10)

# Display the map
m_1
```

I receive no errors, just a grey box where the map should be -- even the Plus and Minus signs are in the upper left corner.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71499508/openstreetmap-not-loading-in-folium-greyed-rectangle

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenStreetMap not loading in Folium (greyed rectangle)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71499508/openstreetmap-not-loading-in-folium-greyed-rectangle)

Answer (score 1):

It works for me, with **max_zoom** and **control_scale** set:

```
folium.Map(tiles='openstreetmap', zoom_start=10, max_zoom=23, control_scale=True, location=[42.32, -71.0589])
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately not for me. I read on a github forum that someone had a similar issue and it was due to a server firewall. I'm running it on a uni server, but would be surprised if that was it tbh. Strange.

Answer (score 0):

Review the network traffic in your browser's developer console to see if the map tiles are returning a 200. I tested your code and it worked for me which indicates your code is correct but the map tiles are failing to load on your network.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I just checked, and you are correct, I'm not getting a 200, but a 403 error.

Comment: Well, I have more information about the problem, but, it is still not solved, as I don't know why I'm getting the 403, and still a grey map :(

Comment: Sorry to say but that isn't something anyone here can help you with. Myself and another user tested your code and the map tiles load on our networks. The issue is mostly likely with the filtering on your network. If you are able, test your code on a another network to further confirm the loading issue.

Comment: Also, I ran your code as a .py file, not in IDLE or a notebook and outputted the map to an HTML page.

Comment: So confusing. I've tried it on my personal, and work laptop, and also on on the uni and my home network. And get the same response.

Comment: Maybe update your question with your complete code. Are you running a .py file and outputting HTML? I ask because your code looks like you're using IDLE or a jupyter notebook.

Comment: Fixed it! I was running in a jupyter notebook, and with Brave -- which has never given me problems in the past, but I just tried with Chrome, and it works. Thanks for your help along the way

Comment: Glad it is resolved. Brave being a security focused browser was probably blocking the map tile requests, hence the 403 forbidden HTTP code you received in the network requests.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it resolves your issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
import folium 
map = folium.Map ( tiles='openstreetmap', zoom_start=10, max_zoom=23, control_scale=True, location = [-1.373, 36.853])
map.save("Map1.html")
```

I created this on the terminal opened via the folder i was using. I am a brave browser user. However, when i opened the html file with the browser, it returns a gray page and a 418 error(on inspecting the web page on the console) , which is an "extra web security measure".
I switched to mozilla firefox (a different browser) and my web page shows with the map.